# Efficiency of STL's copy function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to construct a set of unique words from a list of entries, each of which has a vector of strings.

So I made a function called Insert, which gets called for each of the entries like this:

```
for( auto & e : _Entries )
    _Dictionary.Insert( begin( e.getNameWords( ) ), end( e.getNameWords( ) ) );
```

The class _Dictionary internally has a set (the STL container) and I wrote the function Insert as follows:

```
template< typename InputIterator >
void Insert( InputIterator first, InputIterator last )
{
    for( auto it = first ; it != last ; ++it )
        _AllWords.insert( *it );
 }
```

In my case, calling Insert for all entries in _Entries took an average of 570 milliseconds.

Then I thought that I should use the functions that the STL already has to do the same thing that the for loop in Insert does, so I changed the function Insert to the following:

```
template< typename InputIterator >
void Insert( InputIterator first, InputIterator last )
{
    copy( first, last, inserter( _AllWords, begin( _AllWords ) ) );

}
```

I was expecting this to

1. be more correct, and
2. be at least as fast, if not more

(guided by the philosophy of letting the STL do as much for you as you can). However, I was surprised to notice that this implementation actually took longer; not much more, but a consistent 200 milliseconds more than the previous for-loop based implementation.

I know this is an essentially trivial speed difference, but I'm still surprised.

So my question is: why is my implementation faster?

Note: I am compiling this with clang's version 3.5.2 with the libc++ standard library and with the -O3 flag, under Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) for us :)

Comment: How did you actually measure?

Comment: Note that identifiers beginning with an underscore, followed by a capital letter, are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I know, but I think you should try using the STL if it should do essentially the same and then compare; which is the reason of this post.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I measured with the difference between <chrono>'s high_resolution_clock::now( ) before and after.

Comment: @William Make sure to take the average execution time of a significant number of calls (10000 or so).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
copy( first, last, inserter( _AllWords, begin( _AllWords ) ) );
```

ends up calling this version of [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert):

```
iterator insert( iterator hint, const value_type& value );
```

with `begin()` as the hint. That is, typically, not where you're going to want to insert each value. As a result, you're just making the container do more work trying to figure out where to add your values since your `hint` is *as bad as possible*.

But note that there is also this overload of `insert`:

```
template< class InputIt >
void insert( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

which you should just use<sup>†</sup>:

```
template< typename InputIterator >
void Insert( InputIterator first, InputIterator last )
{
    _AllWords.insert(first, last);
}
```

And side-note, `_AllWords` is a reserved identifier.

---

<sup>†</sup>Although based on this [note](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert#Notes):

> The overloads (5-6) are often implemented as a loop that calls the overload (3) with `end()` as the hint; they are optimized for appending a sorted sequence (such as another set) whose smallest element is greater than the last element in `*this`

That seems like a really specific goal to optimize against, which you may or may not satisfy, so probably you shouldn't use this overload, and your initial loop is just fine.

Comment: Thanks! That does look much better. It's still 100ms slower, but I guess that falls into stack-unwinding overhead?

Comment: @William Updated my answer.

Comment: Unless the small speed difference is actually important (and if someone's still using `std::set` I doubt it is), I see no reason not to use the range version of `insert`.

Comment: @T.C. Actually, even though the function was called around a million times with approximately 5 words each time, and even though there were a lot of duplicate words, I ended up storing everything in a vector and just sorting and removing duplicates when all the words were in. This halved the running time. I'm ashamed I didn't try this first...